# class org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner in Maven

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I want to use the class  `org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner` in my test but there is no way to find it in maven

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-tests-utils</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

I've tried as well adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-mockito-release-full</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.9</version>
</dependency>
```

But I got the error:

```
Missing artifact org.powermock:powermock-mockito-release-full:jar:1.4.9
```

I also tried to install it locally, with the same result

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\tmp\migration\lib\mockito\powermock-mockito-1.5.4-full.jar -DgroupId=org.powermock -DartifactId=powermock-mockito-release-full -Dversion=1.5.4 -Dpackaging=jar
```

I also change the pom to this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-mockito-release-full</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

But I have still the error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Class<PowerMockRunner> cannot be resolved 
     to a type
```

Running

```
mvn test
```

that is the result

```
Tests run: 109, Failures: 109, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.235 sec <<< FAILURE!
```

Comment: This looks like an IDE configuration issue. If that's correct, what IDE are you using and did you check to see if after adding the `powermock-module-junit4` dependency in the pom, the change also reflects in the classpath configuration?

Comment: can you run the class from command line?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: Who where you talking to? Perhaps @kuhajeyan was suggesting running `mvn test` to see if you have the same issue...

Comment: @AmadeuCabanilles  Where you able to solve this issue?